# Unable to update 2013 SP1 to Web 8 for CM

Tags: web8

facing issue while upgrading db of Tridion 2013 SP1 database to Web 8 for Content manager.

Tried 2 times but its not happening and getting this error message :-
[image]

Any clue? I have tried twice from scratch...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answer, and issues was :-

After DB restore from Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8, there were some duplicate records, and after removing all the duplicate records, add the constraint.

Comment: Naveen, can you mark this post as the answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks as though the upgrade script is unable to cope with your database. You should contact support. Modifying either your database or the upgrade script without the approval of support will leave you with an unsupported system, so only they can help you with this.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I have already contacted to SDL support team, Just trying my luck here if someone has faced the same issue as i have faced...

Comment: Not the fastest, but I would probably setup a new 2013 SP1 database and find the AK_PUBLISH_STATE_01 constraint (which you seem to be missing in your real DB) and then try to re-create it. Could be that it's the only issue in your DB, and maybe at some point in time someone thought it would be a good idea to try this to solve some other problem?